# Create text box on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, textbox

Initially when the page loads the table will be displayed normally but when I click on the edit label it should make the first name value as text box to make it editable. I will enter the value and hit enter it will submit the form. I am really confused how to achieve this.

This is the sample table I have, I couldn't go beyond this.

```
<label id="edit" style="cursor:pointer; color:blue;">edit</label>

<table>
    <tr><td>First Name: </td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name: </td>
        <td>Wright</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdRWC/1/)

​

Comment: I tried to add `<SCRIPT>       $('#edit').on("click", function() { $('<input type="text" />').attr({id: 'firstName' });alert("jwsd");}); </SCRIPT>` in the td element but didn't understand how to attach it to the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
    var $table = $('table');
    if ($table.find('input').length) return;
    $table.find('td:nth-child(2)').html(function(i, v) {
        return '<input value=' + v + '>';
    })
})

$('table').on('blur', 'input', function() {
    $('table input').replaceWith(function() {
        return this.value;
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnuDh/

Comment: There is a bug in the code, if you keep on clicking the edit button it adds `<input` in the text box and `>>` at the end of the text box

Comment: @user525146 Here yes, I have added an if statement in the fiddle, I'll update it.

Comment: I found a bug in the code, haven't noticed it before. When I change the value and click somewhere `return this.value` keeps the edited value instead of the previous value.

Answer (score 4):

Don't complicate the things. Just add another `<td>` tag wit textbox and make it hidden. Then add some jsvascript which binds to click on label, hides `<td>` with static text and shows `<td>` with textbox.
BTW you do not need label here, `<span>` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

check out the following link

[How To Create TextBox Dynamically using Javascript and Read Control Value In Code Behind](https://www.codeguru.co.in/2008/03/how-to-create-textbox-dynamically-using.html)

Comment: @Shivanandam Updated the link

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `contentEditable` support from HTML5 and javascript `keyPress` event .  Please try this link http://jsfiddle.net/rdRWC/8/ .

**HTML**

```
<div id="edit" style="border:1px solid #ccc" contenteditable="true" onkeypress="submitForm(event,this)">edit</div>
```

**JS**

```
   function submitForm(e , t){
    var keyPressed = e.which;
if(e.which == 13){  //Pressed Enter Key
      alert("Do your Form Submittion Here");
   }
```

}

Comment: I am supporting IE 6,7,8. I am assuming HTML5 wouldn't work in those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a textbox when the user clicks, you should have the text box hidden using the CSS

```
display: none
```

then, when the user clicks, just call:

```
$('#textboxid').show();
```

The reason why I discourage creating a textbox dynamically is because creating HTML is more difficult, and harder to maintain than just showing and hiding a textbox.